# Removing crosshair in the center of plot.circular plot in R

Tags: r, plot, circular-dependency

I am looking for a way to remove the center crosshair in  a circular plot generated with the package circular. See below example code. The crosshair is produced by the axis.circular function in the code below. Somehow when the axes are added, it also adds the center cross. I would be very very thankful to anybody who could help me get rid of it. I want to add arrows and lines in my plot and the large center cross is just always in the way.

BTW: when I try to change attributes of the axis, it only changed the ticks NOT the cross.

Thanks a lot in advance! 
Lukas

```
data.vm <- circular::rvonmises(n=100,mu=circular(0), kappa=3)
plot(data.vm, stack=TRUE, bins=150,axes=FALSE) 
axis.circular(at=0, labels=c("Example"),tcl.text=0.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`axis.circular` calls the function `circular:::AxisCircularRad`, which ends with the hard-coded line:

```
text(0, 0, "+", cex = 1)
```

So, to avoid printing the crosshairs you'll have to edit the function yourself by removing this line of code.  For a permanent solution, you could copy the functions into your own package, and edit it there.  As a temporary fix, you can use

```
fixInNamespace('AxisCircularRad', ns = "circular")
```

and the delete the offending line of code at the end of the function

[image]